# Why does the Haftara of Mishpatim end before it starts?

Tags: haftarah, mishpatim, yirmiyahu--book-of

The Haftara of Mishpatim starts at Yirmiyahu Ch. 34:8 and continues to the end of the chapter. It then jumps to Ch. 33 verses 25-26, some 8 verses before it started.

Obviously we do not want to end at 34:22 "... `and I shall make the cities of Yehuda desolate without an inhabitant`".

We occasionally jump forward, like the week before - Yisro - where we go from 7:8 to 9:4.

The question is: **Isn't there an issue jumping backwards?** (I seem to have this in mind, but cannot find any reference to it.)

Comment: May be of interest: [Divrei Chaim blog: the haftarah that goes backwards](http://divreichaim.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/haftarah-that-goes-backwards.html). He brings  S.A. O.C. 144 (but mentions M.B. #6 and #9, that say it's talking of a different situation, and not applicable today). He brings a "solution" in the name of R. Chaim Kanievsky to, instead, read on to the end of Ch. 35. (See also my comment there, referencing the _Seder ha-Tefilah_ in the _Mishneh Torah_.)

Comment: Thank you @TamirEvan - your comment deserves to be an answer.

Comment: http://shtikles.weeklyshtikle.com/2012/09/skipping-around.html

Comment: Do all traditions have this Haftarah with the skip, or are you referring to a specific tradition?

Comment: @DoubleAA - all Chumashim that I've checked have the Haftara this way. For some reason nobody prints the version suggested by the Rambam - to continue to the end of the next chapter. (as per Tamir's note above.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I have a _Tanakh_, given to me by the IDF at the end of basic training, which gives the _Haftarah_ for the Ashkenazic and Sephardic customs as described in the question, but for the Yemenite custom it gives Yirmiyahu 34:8-35:19. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah#Haftarot_for_Exodus

Comment: Don't we repeat at Eikhah the penultimate verse to avoid finishing on a negative one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you are thinking of is codified in [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 144:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.144.1?lang=bi).

See [this shiur](https://rabbikaganoff.com/an-unusual-haftarah-tthat-of-parshas-mishpatim/) from R. Kaganoff for a comprehensive discussion of this topic as it relates to the *haftarah* for Mishpatim.

In summary, he presents three approaches that may allow the practice of jumping backwards in this case:

1. The rule only prohibits jumping backwards in Trei Asar, this *haftarah* is from Yirmeyahu.
2. The rule only applies when reading from a scroll, not a bound volume.
3. The rule does not apply to adding verses as a 'concluding song' to the *haftarah*.

---

Some key quotes:

> The question is whether the rule prohibiting *medalgin lemafrei’a*, reading verses of a book out of order, applies only to the book of *Trei Asar*, or is it prohibited in **any** *sefer navi*. If it refers only to *Trei Asar*, then reversing direction at the end of the *haftarah* of *Hadavar*, which is from the book of *Yirmiyahu*, does not present any problem.
>
> The authorities dispute which interpretation of the *beraisa* is correct. The *Kesef Mishneh*, indeed, rules that *ein medalgin lemafrei’a* applies only to *Trei Asar* and nowhere else. However, the *Magen Avraham* disagrees and understands that *ein medalgin lemafrei’a* applies to the works of any of the prophets. It is possible that our custom of skipping backwards when reading *Hadavar* is based on the *Kesef Mishneh*’s understanding of the *Gemara*.

> [T]he *Terumas Hadeshen* contends, those who explain that *Chazal* prohibited switching prophets in mid-*haftarah* because of *tircha detzibura* will conclude that this is permitted when the *haftarah* is in book form ... Based on this approach of the *Terumas Hadeshen*, we may be able to permit going back to two earlier *pesukim* to conclude the *haftarah* of *Hadavar*, if we assume that the prohibition of *ein medalgin lemafrei’a* is because of *tircha detzibura*.

> Other authorities provide a different reason to permit reading *Sos Asis* after a *haftarah* from a different *navi*. They explain that these verses are not considered part of the *haftarah* but a concluding song after the *haftarah* (*Beis Yosef, Orach Chayim* 144, quoting *Nemukei Yosef*; *Levush* ad loc. 144:2) ... [A]dding some verses for a pleasant conclusion is not considered part of the *haftarah*, and therefore does not violate the *takkanas chachamim*.

Comment: Great resources; funny thing is that the only reason I noticed this was because I set the Haftara scrolls; always hunting for the start and then the end. (And getting really good at it after all these years.)