# Haftarat Shuva - Skipping backwards?

Tags: haftarah, aseres-yemei-teshuva, haazinu, vayelech

Some communities read selections from three of the Trei Asar - Hoshea, Yoel and Michah - as the *haftarah* on Shabbat Shuva (the shabbat between Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur.) (See e.g. [Mishnah Berurah 428:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.428.23?lang=bi).)

I have been in synagogues where they were read in the order Hoshea - Michah - Yoel. I have also seen the *haftarah* printed in *chumashim* in this order. E.g.

[image]

What is the basis for allowing this practice?

When Trei Asar is written in full, Yoel precedes Michah, and [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 144:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.144.1?lang=bi) rules:

> ובתרי עשר מדלגין מנביא לנביא ובלבד שלא ידלג מסוף הספר לתחלתו
>
> In Trei Asar we skip from one prophet to another, provided that one doesn't skip from the end of the book towards the beginning.

This rule is clarified by [Magen Avraham](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.144.4?lang=bi) as:

> לנביא של תרי עשר לא ידלג מנביא לנביא למפרע
>
> One does not skip backwards from one prophet to another within Trei Asar.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94902/who-uses-which-haftarah-for-shabbat-shuva?rq=1

Comment: I'm just guessing, but an Italian book was edited this way, saying that Ashkenazim insert Yoel between the two other parts. Isn't that possible that this note somehow disappeared over the centuries?

Comment: @kazi or a note saying "some replace the above with the following" or "some conclude instead"

Comment: This is the same question as the one I asked at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34583/501

Comment: @DannySchoemann Not quite the same question. [Mishnah Berurah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.144.9?lang=bi) quotes those that permit skipping backwards within one navi (like we do for Mishpatim), but it seems that no one permits jumping backwards  from one navi to another within Trei Asar.

Comment: http://shtikles.weeklyshtikle.com/2012/09/skipping-around.html h/t @msh

Comment: I guess reading in this order is just a mistake. Probably the Chumash prints it in that order bc it's printed as Haftarah for Vayelekh and the Dagul Merevava says Micha is for Vayelekh. And then after it prints what is said for Haazinu.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Danny Schoemann in a comment, this question is very similar to one that he asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34583/why-does-the-haftara-of-mishpatim-end-before-it-starts).

[My answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95033/14850) to his question linked to a [*shi'ur* by R. Kaganoff](https://rabbikaganoff.com/an-unusual-haftarah-tthat-of-parshas-mishpatim/), where he presented three possible approaches. One of those would seem to apply here as well.

If one is reading from a bound book, instead of a scroll, then he writes that:

> Based on th[e] approach of the *Terumas Hadeshen*, we may be able to permit going back ... if we assume that the prohibition of *ein medalgin lemafrei’a* is because of *tircha detzibura*.

I.e. the Terumat HaDeshen explains that the prohibition to jump backwards is because of the inconvenience this causes to those present while they wait for the reader to find the new place. This wouldn't apply where the *haftarah* is being read from a bound book.